# Getting list item id from query function returns incorrect value when multiple items are selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a function that is supposed to return ids of selected items from a list. It returns an expected value only when one file is selected. When you select multiple or none, it returns 0. I don't mind it returning 0 when nothing is selected, but how could I make it return a string of all ids when multiple files are selected? This is the function I'm using :

```
private int GetListItemIDFromQueryParameter()
{
    int result;
    Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["SPListItemId"], out result);
    return result;
}
```

If more code should be added, please let me know.

///

> CommandAction="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&SPListId={SelectedListId}"

It returns a value of an item's ID if only one item is selected - if you select multiple, it returns 0, just as if you selected nothing.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add your input url with querystring.

Comment: Not quite sure if this is what you're asking for, but my best guess is this - (added in post after ///). Thank you for answering and if there is anything more I should provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below code ( Tested and Working)

```
private ArrayList GetListItemIDFromQueryParameter()
    {

        string itemId;
        ArrayList listIds = new ArrayList();
        if (Request.QueryString.Get("SPListItemId") != null)
        {
            itemId = Request.QueryString.Get("SPListItemId");
            listIds.Add(itemId);
        }

        return listIds;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I haven't tried it. I just assumed it returned null when I got 0 int in both when I checked multiple files and checked nothing. Thank you very much!